# Не работает goBack() в react-navigation

Tags: react-native

Есть вкладка уведомлений, с нее мне нужна навигация назад по системной кнопке назад. Пробовал вызывать просто goBack(), пробовал передавать в него null и пробовал с помощью NavigationActions.back(). Результата нет, происходит ничего. Подскажите в чем проблема.

Upd: обертку setTimeout тоже пробовал.

```
useEffect(() => {
const handleBack = () => {
  navigation.goBack(null)
  // navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.back())

  return true
}

const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
  “hardwareBackPress”,
  handleBack
)

return () => backHandler.remove()
```

}, [navigation])

Comment: `let history = useHistory();  history.goBack();`

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов это обращение к реакт роутеру, а у меня react-navigator на нейтиве.

Comment: Мдаа. Действительно

Comment: Вы пробовали проверять действительный ли путь назад?  `const canGoBack = navigation.canGoBack();
  if (canGoBack) {
    navigation.goBack();
  } else {
    doSomething();
  }`

Comment: @Александр я к вечеру осознал свою ошибку. Воспринимал нейтив навигатор как браузерный роутер и думал, что там так же пишется история (хотя чтение стейта должно было натолкнуть на определенную мысль). В общем нужно описывать каждый сценарий роутинга, который подразумевает переходы вперед и назад, с иерархией.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй:

```
const navigation = useNavigation();
....
navigation.goBack();
```

Comment: Это все было прописано, я уже выше ответил, что осознал ошибку.